# AngularJS - Send data from one application to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

So I have two `AngularJS` applications, and I want to have an initial sign in at application 1, which then redirects to application 2 along with a token.

One way to fix this is by sending the token in the `URL` to the second application. But what if I want to keep the token hidden, is there a way to parse data from one `AngularJS` application to another without having it show within the `URL`.

PS: The database is not an option unfortunately :'-(

Comment: Hidden from whom? If the token is needed for authentication / authorization then you'll have to send it with subsequent requests anyway.

Comment: cookie or localstorage?

Comment: @zeroflagL: What I mean is that the token should not be visible in the `URL`. Something like `www.abc.com/token/0001` would therefore not do.

@aet: Cookies would be a solution. Do you have some great examples for how this would work? (Searching solution now, but still ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

if you want encrypt token, you can use custom encryption between two application
But that can be sniffed

https://github.com/pussinboots/angularjs-crypto

Answer (score 1):

Hope you can make use of Local Storage, That is only solution if you dont have any backend , if you can conculde with Backend Then you can design one api, which is responsible to store the data in Json File. And Another api for retrieve.

You can define api in node , its very much easy